# Wildfly 14.0.1 RestEasy - how to specify json provider?

Tags: wildfly, resteasy, jackson-databind

I'm using JavaEE 7, but since WF supports JSON-B it sometimes uses JSON-B and sometimes Jackson. And the problem is that it sometimes uses one provider for serialization and different for deserialization and cannot ser/deser java.util.Date.


I've tried excluding single provider but it again doesn't work. Is it possible to configure this somehow easy?

Comment: how are you excluding dependency? share your jboss-deployment-structure file

Comment: Is this really what one should do? Shouldn't WF provide same default implementation (provider) for serialization and deserialization? Why do we even have to configure this?